# Failed to resolve: com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0 in android studio project

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I exported a project from eclipse and import it to android studio.in that I added on my project the **library dependency com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0**, from the **Project Structure dialog** of Android Studio, but when I build the project with gradle (with the Sync Gradle button), I get the error "**Failed to resolve:** **com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0"** .but when i am adding that same lib dependencies to a project which i have created in android studio,there its working fine.can anyone plz help me.what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open your android studio,click File->Settings,in the search box type in "gradle"
On the left side,under "Build Tools",there is "Gradle",click it
Then,on the right side,you will find "Offline work",yours maybe checked,make it unchecked
Click "OK" to finish the operation
Finally Sync Project with Gradle Files again
You can have a try